# Breeze.js 1.53 possible breaking changes from Breeze.js 1.5.1

Tags: angularjs, breeze, hottowel

I am using a subdomain on my hosted website for this application.  So imi.{url} goes directly to the folder with the app.  Breeze 1.5.3

I have another site running on a different subdomain that uses 3 breeze controllers successfully.  Breeze 1.5.1

Both apps Angular 1.3n

The imi (problem) app uses a single breeze controller with the default name BreezeController.

The app is a Hot Towel SPA and runs fine in VS2013 against the web hosted MSSQL database.

When I upload the website to the serve the first call to the breeze/Breeze/Metadata gets a 404

http://imi.mysite.com/imi/breeze/Breeze/Metadata

in the other app

http://qui.mysite.com/qui/breeze/Quoting/Metadata

works fine.

I have compared the webconfig files and adjusted the imi webconfig to match the working app

these are the files being using in the working app

```
 <package id="Angular.UI" version="0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Angular.UI.Bootstrap" version="0.12.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Animate" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Route" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Sanitize" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angular-translate.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Angular" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Angular.Directives" version="1.3.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Client" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.WebApi2" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.WebApi2.EF6" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="HotTowel.Angular" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="HotTowel.Angular.Breeze" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

And these are the relevant files being used in the new app, running on the same web server

```
package id="Angular.UI.Bootstrap" version="0.12.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Angular.UI.Utils" version="0.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Animate" version="1.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Route" version="1.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Sanitize" version="1.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angular-moment" version="0.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angular-smart-table" version="1.4.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Angular" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Angular.Directives" version="1.3.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Client" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.WebApi2" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="HotTowel.Angular" version="2.3.3" targetFramework="net45"
```

In the 1.5.3 app the first call to Breeze/Metadata fails as described above, though it does not fail when running against the same connection string from Visual Studio.

I have also found that locally the breezeSaveErrorExtensions.js throws an unhandled error that it cannot find breeze when installed exactly as in the 1.5.1 app.

Am I missing a file, do I have some version mismatch or is there a breaking change I am not taking into account?

Comment: Too many moving parts and pieces to answer effectively. I think I would try to eliminate v.1.5.3 as the cause by rolling back to 1.5.1 in the problem app ... and seeing if the problem is still there. Also what URL does return metadata and how does it differ from the URL that the Breeze client is producing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no evidence of a breaking change between Breeze 1.51 and 1.53.

The problem was failure to have the Breeze dlls fully-trusted.  This was not a problem when run locally but of course became a problem when deployed.

In Chrome dev tools there was just a 404 failure to return Metadata.  Could have cleared it up much more quickly if I had also tested in Firefox which correctly said the problem was that BreezeWebApi2 needed to be fully trusted.

Adding 
          
to  in the web.config (as I had done long ago but forgotten about in the app mentioned above that worked fine)  resolved the issue.

Moral: browser dev tools have their own strengths and weaknesses and testing with multiple browser tools can be quite helpful in resolving problems.